# Ruby on Rails 4.0 length validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I would like to validate my code's length.
It suppose to take a number from a range in between 13 and 16 but it should exclude 14.
I cannot find any clever way to do it in Model.

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :number, :length => { in: 13..16 }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
validates :number, :length => { in: [13,15,16] }
```

However, it smells like you probably should be using a regular expression.